# In what game do you play a knight fighting skeletons in a cemetery at night?

Tags: story-identification, video-games

Trying to find a game I played as a kid, most likely on a PS2 (99% sure).

It's an old game where, I believe, you play as a knight, and during the first few levels it is night time and you fight skeletons in a cemetery. Not much to go off of but thanks for whatever help.

EDIT: I really want to say it was made by Capcom, but I can't be sure. It was also **not** a sidescroller, it was a full 3D action/adventure.

Comment: First thought was [Ghosts'n'Goblins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_%27n_Goblins), but that's a side scroller. Maybe [Dragon's Lair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon's_Lair)?

Comment: @NiallC., Nah, definitely not Dragon's Lair, lol.

Comment: What system/console was it for?

Comment: @Richard, I'm 99% sure PS2.

Comment: Do you remember the perspective?  First Person?  Close Third Person?  High Angle Third Person?

Comment: @N.Soong Per [Meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/319/1027), sci-fi/fantasy video games are on topic for us.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question as given describes a wide variety of games in the fantasy genre. I would say more detail is needed.

Comment: @Omegacron, sorry about that lol, couldn't think of any more details. No worries, as I've already found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **Maximo: Ghosts to Glory** (h/t to @Dedpool)

Other similar games include;

- [**Medievil**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediEvil) (for the PS1)
- **Dark Souls (I or II)**
- **Castlevania - Lord of Shadows**
- **Knights of the Temple**

Comment: I'd advise to make separate answers out of the different games. If the OP accepts this answer, it's not clear _which_ game it was, without a comment (that may never come).

Comment: @SQB - OP seems to be quite chatty. If any of these prove to be correct, I'll delete the others accordingly.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I personally prefer the multiple answers-solution, but your method should work as well.

Comment: This was pretty much exactly the list I was thinking of myself.  Course we are talking about very generic nouns for RPG's here (knights, skeletons)...

Comment: It was Maximo! Wow, that game is so nostalgic. How did I forget it? Lol thanks so much.

Answer (score 7):

For the PS2 you are talking Maximo: Ghosts to Glory, the spiritual successor to Ghost n Goblins. it is technically part of the franchise. It was followed by a sequel Maximo Vs The Army of Zin.

Here is a game play video.