# PC Game: Skeletons as Enemies at start and in a dream or dimension with third person sword fighting

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I have been trying to find a old pc game, with the description: A third person sword fighting with skeletons (just beginner enemies ig) as enemies and waking up on a empty street, traps where you have to jump across spikes and finding a white (blue glowing) sword to defeat skeletons.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How old is "old?"  1980s?  1990s?  Was there any dialog or a soundtrack?

Comment: @Davidw I cannot tell, I myself am young, it was probably before 2009 or 2006

Comment: Sounds like any number of games. Legacy of Kain immediately fittings to mind, or Medievil

Comment: @Valorum I checked both the game, but none of them match, also the main character is human. I probably cant tell how old the game is because I played it around 2011 or 2012. It could have been released before I was born or maybe sometime after I was born, I don't really know

Comment: At the beginning, is your primary weapon throwing rocks you pick up off the ground?

Comment: Just to clarify, third person over the shoulder? Isometric like *Diablo*? More sidescrolling? 3d graphics? 2d? Were there lighting effects or static lighting?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It was a 3d game, the third person was similar/same as the 1st splinter cell game where the camera is directly behind the character, I think it had static lighting, about the primary weapon, I don't remember it.

Comment: So far, I've only come up with partially matching answers, but you can accept a correct one by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent opportunity to [edit] in details that you now realize weren't in the question ("It can't be *Fazbear's Fabulous Adventure* because the protagonist was Asian and it was set in a small village in England.")

Comment: You might also check out https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60259/23243, which has many answers for games fighting skeletons.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for *[Alone in the Dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alone_in_the_Dark)* by Infogrames.

> In 1924, Jeremy Hartwood, a noted artist and owner of the Louisiana mansion Derceto (named after the Syrian deity), has committed suicide by hanging himself. His death appears suspicious yet seems to surprise nobody, for Derceto is widely reputed to be haunted by an evil power. The case is quickly dealt with by the police and soon forgotten by the public. The player assumes the role of either Edward Carnby—a private investigator who is sent to find a piano in the loft for an antique dealer—or Emily Hartwood, Jeremy's niece, who is also interested in finding the piano because she believes a secret drawer in it has a note in which Jeremy explains his suicide. Whether Carnby or Hartwood, the character goes to the mansion to investigate.

The early recurring opponents are zombies, not skeletons, but early on, you get a sword to fight with (which breaks, necessitating to to find another one, which isn't magic, bit it's significantly better), and there is definite platforming, although puzzles are almost as important.

One departure, as the game that likely inspired *Resident Evil*, it uses tank controls, which is not over-the-shoulder.

### Long play

Answer (score 1):

Another partial match is *[The Elder Scrolls Adventure: Redguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Adventures:_Redguard)*.

> Cyrus is a mercenary under the employ of the Khajiit crime boss S'rathra. In Wayrest, he receives a letter from his old mentor and friend, Tobias. Tobias urges Cyrus to come to Stros M'Kai, where his sister has gone missing. Cyrus travels by ship, but as he nears the island, a group of Restless League pirates raids the ship. He dispatches them without trouble and the ship docks at the harbor. At the Draggin' Tale inn, Tobias fills Cyrus in on further details.

Skeletons don't appear until later in the story (your first opponents are pirates), but it's third-person over-the-shoulder swordfighting, there's platforming, and part of the finale involves Cyrus wielding the "Soul Sword" against a dragon.

### Gameplay

### Skeletons

[image: Skelton facing the player]

### Soul sword

[image: Cyrus using the blue glowing Soul Sword to open a door]